# css changes doesn't take affect in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

Recently I have encountered with a strange problem:from time to time visual studio ignored changes I made in .css. **Only when I recreate .css with another! name changes become visible.** When I clear solution and delete .css visual still render! deleted .css .Has anybody same problems or it is only my bug?

Comment: You're actually asking about your _browser_, which is caching the file.

Comment: You can clear the cache of your browser (Windows) by pressing Ctrl+F5 to have it reload a "brand-new" version. Additionally, consider [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache) on preventing caching of CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, make sure web caching is disabled in your project although Visual Studio Disables this mechanism automatically. Also, you can try Incognito/Private-Browsing mechanism in your browser if it supports. Another reason may be using unchanged css files. Try Clear Browsing Data to understand what causes the problem.